# Crashed site - Server unable to read .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permissions, controls

My website crashed when a plugin was installed ( to the wrong location) and any atttmpt to visit the web site via a browser gets the response

"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe"

I was able to delete the offending plugin but this has not cured anything.

When I try to open a file to read it the response is "Something went wrong. File content can not be retrieved."

I cannot therefor edit any file.

I cannot gain access via FTP to the site

If I attempt to overwrite the main site from Staging, this process fails

If I try to restore the main site from a previously down-loaded back up zip file the process fails.

I do not appear to have a Command Line capability in Control Panel

Here are the permission codes in the root of WP

```
.htAccess  File = 644
public_html folder = 711
.pki       folder = 700
Databese   folder = 755
public_html folder =755
mysqldumps folder = 755
staging  folder   = 755
```

As administrator, I can access the WP control panel and can open up the directories and sub-directories.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, but it seems you mix a few issues here. Sure, it might be that a malicious wordpress plugin lead to a corrupted configuration file. But that definitely does have nothing to do with you being unable to access files via FTP (if that worked before), you being unable to restore a backup (if that worked before), you being unable to edit any file (if that has worked before). Those are completely separate things.

Comment: "`.htAccess  File = 644`" - Presumably you mean `.htaccess` (all lowercase)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes, FTP worked many times before. It is the only site I ever use FTP and the FTP client settings are configured  that site only and nothing has changed.
As I said before the hosting server responded with "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe".
So it appears the server has been programmed to close down any "edit" or access capability as a safeguarding measure.
The result is I cannot edit any file or change permissions via the CP.

Comment: I got through to the admin for the hosting server and they fixed the permissions. Big relief.